# Can't Autowire List of objects in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating a REST service in Spring boot. I am creating a list of objects(`List<Record>`) as bean in config class and trying to use in service class by auto wiring, but I am always getting empty list, I have tried in constructor injection as well but not working. Below is the code,

Main app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

REST controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;
```

Service

```
 @Service
    public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
        @Autowired
    public ServiceImpl(List<Record> records) {
        System.out.println(records);  //------------------->getting empty list [null]
        data = new Data();
        customers = Arrays.asList("John", "James", "Calvin");
    }
```

Config class

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    
    @Bean
public List<Record> records(){
    List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
    records.add(new Record("d"));
    return records;
  }
}
```

I can't find what I am doing wrong please advise.

Project folder structure
[image: Project folder structure]

Comment: use `List<Record>` in `AppConfig` instead of `List<String>`

Comment: my mistake, it actually has to be List<Record>, even with that as return type, I am getting  [null] as sysout

Comment: Because `List<Record>` instructs spring to inject all `Record` instances into this service. However you don't have any `Record` bean and thus it is empty. Either add an `@Qualifier` to inject the list you prepared yourself, or just register a `Record` to let Spring create a list of dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
public class Record {
    private final String s;

    public Record(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Record{" +
                "s='" + s + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


@Service
public class RecordService {
    private final List<Record> recordList;

    public RecordService(List<Record> recordList) {
        this.recordList = recordList;
    }

}

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public List<Record> recordList() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Record("a"), new Record("b"));
    }
}
```

Everything gets injected as expected (spring boot version 2.3.1.RELEASE)

From the question it looks like you did everything right and I basically just confirmed that spring / spring boot can deal with cases like this.
Which spring boot/spring version do you use?

Comment: The actual problem was not only spring but also the way the object was created

Comment: @java_dev if you have found the problem do you mind sharing for others to know what it was?